# WEBRTC Object #<RTCPeerConnection> has no method 'processSignalingMessage'

Tags: webrtc

I have problems with the WebRTC:
I use this code from one example about Video calls.

```
 if (new_connection) {
       console.log('New Peer Connection');
       var peer_connection = {};
       peer_connection.connection_id = msg.from_connection_id;
       peer_connection.pc = createPeerConnection(peer_connection.connection_id,
       false);
       peer_connections.push(peer_connection);
       $('#remote').prepend(remoteVideoHtml.replace('remoteVideoId', 'peer' +
       peer_connection.connection_id));
 }

 //Now process the SDP JSON Blob received
 for (var i in peer_connections) {
       if (peer_connections[i].connection_id == msg.from_connection_id) {
             try {
                  peer_connections[i].pc.processSignalingMessage(msg.data);
             }catch (e) {
       console.log("Failed to create processSignalingMessage, exception: " +    e.message);                            
 }
```

I need help because I have one problem here.

```
                      peer_connections[i].pc.processSignalingMessage(msg.data);
```

The problem is:

```
 Object #<RTCPeerConnection> has no method 'processSignalingMessage'
```

I don't know how those functions works and how they are invoqued:

```
pc.onconnecting = function (msg) {
    console.log('onSessionConnecting');
}
pc.onopen = function (msg) {
    console.log('onSessionOpened');
}
pc.onaddstream = function (event) {
    console.log('onRemoteStreamAdded add the remote peers video stream.');
    var url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    $('#peer' + connection_id).attr({
        src: url
    });
}
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The initial version of WebRTC in Chrome was based on ROAP and it used to have a `processSignallingMessage()` method. The current version based on JSEP and it has methods like [`setRometeDescription()`](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#dom-peerconnection-setremotedescription) or [`setLocalDescription()`](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#dom-peerconnection-setlocaldescription) to inject the local SDP and the SDP received from other users.

You can still find this implementation in old versions of Chrome or in Bowser.